# How to map an unbalanced list of lists as functions?

Tags: list-manipulation, map

Given:

```
Map[f, {{a, f, h, m, n, k},{a, b}, {z, d, f, h, k}, {c, d, e}, {c, p}}]
```

I like to have a list of `ordered` functions as follows:

```
{a = f[b], c = f[p], c = f[d, e], z = f[d, f, h, k], a = f[f, h, m, n, k]}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "functions"? In your result, `a` and `c` are defined twice (so the latter evaluations will replace the former ones), so it seems like you don't actually want to define these as functions, do you?

Comment: @lericr: I just want to translate the list to a list of functional forms like the one given as an answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"];

list = {{a, f, h, m, n, k}, {a, b}, {z, d, f, h, k}, {c, d, e}, {c, p}};

HoldForm[#1 = f[##2]] & @@@ Sort[list]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

or use named function.

```
ff[{a_, b__}] := HoldForm[a = f[b]];

{{a, f, h, m, n, k},{a, b}, {z, d, f, h, k}, {c, d, e}, {c, p}} //
Sort //
Map[ff]
```